# I want to move background image and not this red circle thing

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a background image opened but I can't drag it to my preferred location, instead I keep moving this red circle cursor thing. 
Like if I zoom in the image I can't move to the face or the feet

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, could you clarify? What are you trying to achieve, under what editor are you working?

Comment: You actually can, Shift+s .We ask because the tutorials normally do little things without really telling us how they've done it and it is so annoying.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can't drag a background image. To move it use the numbers in the background image section of the properties bar (You can bring this up by pressing <kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D viewport).

[image: BG Image]

2. Zooming has nothing to do with panning. To pan around the 3D viewport use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>MMB</kbd>.
3. The little red circle thing is the 3D cursor. It is for doing operations relitive to a point in space.

As a word of advice, I highly suggest you watch some tutorials on the 3D view and interface before worrying about things like background images.

Answer (score -3):

I finally found the answer, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> then select *Cursor to Center*